# Naming a file based on other files in the folder?

Tags: c#, file, filenames

I have a folder with text files named like this, for example: 0, 1, 2, 3...

I need to check for the highest number in the file names.

For example if I have files 1.txt and 2.txt and 3.txt, I want to get 3.

How could I do that ?

Thanks,

Comment: Which is it? 0 based or 1 based counting?

Comment: It starts at one, but it's irelevent what number it's starting with. What's important is the highest number.

Comment: Consistency is a very important attribute in development, so asking a consistent question is a really good start.

Answer (score 1):

Some LINQ goodness:

```
var maxNumber = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test")
                         .Select(file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
                         .Where(filename => filename.All(ch => char.IsNumber(ch)))
                         .Select(filename => int.Parse(filename))
                         .Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
private static void CreateNewFile()
       {
          string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\test");
          int maxNumb = 0;
          foreach (var item in files)
          {
              FileInfo file = new FileInfo(item);
              maxNumb = Math.Max(maxNumb,     int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName)));
          }
        File.Create(string.Format("{0}.txt", maxNumb++));
       }
```

Hope this  help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework, but it's late and I'm in a good mood so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //set the path to check:
            var path = @"D:\Thefiles";
            //create a dictionary to store the results so we can also remember the file name
            var results = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            //loop all the files
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                //get the name without any extension
                var namePart = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                //try to cast it as an integer; if this fails then we can't count it so ignore it
                int fileNumber = 0;
                if (Int32.TryParse(namePart, out fileNumber))
                {
                    //add to dictionary
                    results.Add(fileNumber, file);
                }
            }
            //only show the largest file if we actually have a result
            if (results.Any())
            {
                var largestFileName = results.OrderByDescending(r => r.Key).First();
                Console.WriteLine("Largest name is {0} and the file name is {1}", largestFileName.Key, largestFileName.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No valid results!");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marco, fair enough, in my defence it was rather late when I did it :)